# Why do we need Eureka and Spring boot load balancer when using Kubernetes not in the cloud?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, netflix-eureka

For microservices architecture **not in the cloud** :

1. What is the difference between the load balancer of Kubernetes and the load balancer of spring cloud?
2. what are the advantages of implementing Eureka and spring boot load balancer when using Kubernetes for deployment rather than using Kubernetes load balancer and kubernetes service discovery?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a complex question but here are my thoughts on the matter:

1. Before actually answering the questions, I must say that my experience setting up Kubernetes load balancer outside of public clouds is a hassle so I wouldn't recommend the approach but, assuming that it is not an issue for you, the main difference is how things are set ut. I would say that the biggest advantage of having it in Kubernetes is that you may also have service mesh solution like Istio that gives you other advantages that just load balancing. Furthermore, it would be easier to do canary (or other special type of) deployments with infrastructure load balancing than with Spring.
2. The only real advantage I see is if you have different teams with responsibility of the infrastructure, deployment and coding. Say if the Kubernetes team is responsible for creating services, deployments, etc and is overloaded, you might get code out faster if your dev team has capacity and competence but, again, there would be no point using Kubernetes then. Or in case you cannot actually create the LoadBalancer service in Kubernetes (as mentioned - not always straightforward in non cloud env)

On a side note, if you are on the way to deploying Kubernetes internally and want to get it to work, have a look at Metallb

Comment: I opened a new question which might be more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73274539/best-technologies-for-non-cloud-environment-for-spring-microservices-with-kubern

Comment: can you explain why it's better to use Metallb then Eureka ?

Comment: I'm not saying Metallb is better than Eureka. I'm just hinting of a possible way to get LoadBalancer for Kubernetes locally. My point is that, Kubernetes LoadBalancer is probably better (let the infrastructure do its job) but is a bit more difficult to set up locally (for non cloud env)

Comment: what does it mean "get LoadBalancer for Kubernetes locally"? you mean load balancer which is not in the client side?

Comment: Kuberetes needs some infrastructure in place to "allow" LoadBalancing. It does not come out of the box. Even though you would always get it in a cloud installation. What I mean by locally here is on your own servers or wherever you will install Kubernetes